# How to copy charts from Excel and embed it to PPT?

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm trying to copy paste charts from Excel to PPT, with the charts embedded into PPT. I'm using the following code:

```
Sub ChartToPresentation()
    ' Uses Early Binding to the PowerPoint Object Model
    ' Set a VBE reference to Microsoft PowerPoint Object Library
    Dim PPApp  As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation

    ' Reference existing instance of PowerPoint
    Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")

    ' Reference active presentation
    Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide

    'Copy "Chart 2" to from "Sheet3" to Slide # 10
    ' Copy "Chart 1" on "Sheet3" as a picture
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Copy

    ' Paste chart  to Slide # 10
    With PPPres.Slides(10).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, _
       Link:=msoTrue)
        ' Align pasted chart
        .Align msoAlignCenters, True
        .Align msoAlignMiddles, True
    End With

    ' Clean up
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set PPPres = Nothing
    Set PPApp = Nothing

    AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")
End Sub
```

When I run this, I get this error: `Run time error. Shapes (unknown member):Invalid request. The specific data type is unavailable`

On line: `With PPPres.Slides(10).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoTrue)`

I'm not sure why I am getting this error. The datatype I specified is one of the datatypes for PasteSpecial. How can I go around this and paste the charts as embedded charts.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to copy is not really the *Chart* but the *Chart Area* of the *Chart Object*.
So try something like:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").ChartObjects("Chart 2").ChartArea.Copy
With PPPres.Slides(10).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoTrue)
    '~~> Rest of your code here
End With
```

Is this what your trying? HTH.